# Spectral database in the UV-Vis/NIR and IR regime

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, databases, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I'm searching for a bunch of spectra (some tens), preferably with intense bands in the Vis spectrum, to play around with (calculating chromaticity, etc.).
They should range from

- 250 nm to 2500 nm (UV-Vis/NIR)
- 400 cm<sup>-1</sup> to 4000 cm<sup>-1</sup> (IR)

and should be available as raw data like jdx format or the like.

I allready know the famous [NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/) and [SDBS](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi), but those have large gaps in the desired spectra, if not one completely missing.

Anybody knows databases where you can search by availability of spectral data in a specific regime?